# How can I get a collection of months between two Dates?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Below is my code. I am only getting the difference between two dates, but I want the name of that month which comes between the from and to dates.

```
public static int GetMonthsBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    if (from > to) return GetMonthsBetween(to, from);

    var monthDiff = Math.Abs((to.Year * 12 + (to.Month - 1)) - (from.Year * 12 + (from.Month - 1)));

    if (from.AddMonths(monthDiff) > to || to.Day < from.Day)
    {
        return monthDiff - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return monthDiff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you retag this? I think it is Java, but am not sure. Did you mean to use the `na` tag?

Comment: @halfer: It's C# as far as i can tell now ... at least this would explain the ">" operator for comparison.

Comment: Do you need the name from the int based month or do you need the calculation or even the month between both, from and to DateTime?

Comment: I want name of months that comes between from and to date

Comment: Hi @Sanjana if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your code you could substract the month difference from the "to" DateTime to get DateTime difference from your input.

```
public static List<DateTime> GetMonthsBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    if (from > to) return GetMonthsBetween(to, from);

    var monthDiff = Math.Abs((to.Year * 12 + (to.Month - 1)) - (from.Year * 12 + (from.Month - 1)));

    if (from.AddMonths(monthDiff) > to || to.Day < from.Day)
    {
        monthDiff -= 1;
    }

    List<DateTime> results = new List<DateTime>();
    for (int i = monthDiff; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        results.Add(to.AddMonths(-i));
    }

    return results;
}
```

To get the name of the month just format the DateTime to "MMM".

```
var dts = GetMonthsBetween(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddMonths(5));
foreach (var dateTime in dts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("MMM"));
}
```

Comment: your ans is right but it is giving only one month in return and i want list of months that comes between from and to date

Comment: I get the months Mar, Apr, May, Jun for the given dates 2017-03-01 and 2017-07-01. My question is that how can I include the last 7th month(July) too?

Comment: For example call the Method `GetMonthsBetween(from, to.AddMonths(1));`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the names of all months between two dates, use something like this:

```
var d1 = new DateTime(2015,6,1);
var d2 = new DateTime(2015,9,1);

var monthlist = new List<string>();
string format = d1.Year == d2.Year ? "MMMM" : "MMMM yyyy";

for (var d = d1; d <= d2; d = d.AddMonths(1))
{
    monthlist.Add(d.ToString(format));
}
```

The full list is now in `monthlist` - you will want to return *that* from your method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Java and JodaTime there are several flaws in your code.

1. You cant use `from > to` to evaluate if a date is after an other. Use `from.isAfter(to)` instead.
2. JodaTime already supplies a method to calculate the amount of whole months between two given Dates `Months.monthsBetween(start,end)`.
3. With the calculated month difference you can instantiate a new DateTime object that holds a date in your desired month and output its name via `yourNewDateTimeObject.month().getAsText()`.

edit: Just found out you're using C# so ignore my text above this. Below here I will try to answer your question in C#.

1. Why dont you just subtract the `from` from the `to` date and obtain your difference?
2. The resulting TimeSpan can be used to determine the amount of whole months between your two given dates.
3. To obtain the resulting month name you could use `yourDateTime.ToString("MMMM");`

Comment: I don't think it's that easy, TimeSpan has no TotalMonths since a month can be variable amount of days.

Comment: @Andre I didn't want to program it for him completely as i suppose he is able to do that by himself. I rather wanted to show an alternative that uses the given classes more efficiently (if implemented properly) than writing everything on his own. Additionaly he could use the NodaTime library.